# Angular 2: Idiomatic way to compose forms from multiple components

Tags: forms, angular

To try to learn Angular 2, I am making a diet tracker to go along with the latest fad diet my wife and I are trying. The book has several questions that can be answered with buttons (How hungry were you—Starving, Very Hungry, etc.) plus an optional text input. There are also checkbox-based questions, plus a date.

I am trying to create a form composed of these multiple components—one for the button questions, one for the checkbox questions. See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jFLSEAv04RXlzeY7UcBt?p=preview).

What I'm curious about is the idiomatic way to compose components—each with its own form elements—into the Daily form. Each subcomponent has form elements, also using `*ngFor` to loop over data in an external file (`question-data.ts`). At the moment, each component has an event emitter that the Daily form subscribes to.

Here is the Daily form template (`src/daily.component.ts`):

```
  <form>
  <h1>Daily Tracker</h1>
  <br>
  <legend>Date</legend>
  <date-picker (onDataEntered)="dateDataEntered($event)"></date-picker>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button-questions
    *ngFor="#b of buttonQuestions"
    [btn]="b"
    (onDataEntered)="buttonDataEntered($event)">
  </button-questions>
  <checkbox-questions
    *ngFor="#c of checkboxQuestions"
    [cbox]="c"
    (onDataEntered)="checkboxDataEntered($event)">
  </checkbox-questions>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Then, for example, the `buttonQuestions` are rendered like so (`src/button-questions.component.ts`):

```
<form>
  <h1>Daily Tracker</h1>
  <br>
  <legend>Date</legend>
  <date-picker (onDataEntered)="dateDataEntered($event)"></date-picker>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button-questions
    *ngFor="#b of buttonQuestions"
    [btn]="b"
    (onDataEntered)="buttonDataEntered($event)">
  </button-questions>
  <checkbox-questions
    *ngFor="#c of checkboxQuestions"
    [cbox]="c"
    (onDataEntered)="checkboxDataEntered($event)">
  </checkbox-questions>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

The `dataEntered()` methods do this (this method is also called on the click of any button):

```
private dataEntered(): void {
  this.btn.inputText = this.inputTextControl.value;
  this.onDataEntered.emit(this.btn);
}
```

The `Daily` component then subscribes to the event emitters on its sub-components and will handle final validation / database interface (I’m still trying to learn that part).

But I feel like the use of raw event listeners on the sub-components is the wrong approach: for example, I don’t know how to wire together validators on my sub-components to validation on the form as a whole. I also don’t think I’m using built-in Angular 2 capabilities fully. And I feel as though this does not follow the principle of loose coupling, as I understand it.

My inclination is that I should somehow gather up the sub-components into a master `ControlGroup` in the `Daily` component, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this approach is preferred, but this is one way.  Child components can use `ControlContainer` from `@angular/forms` to access their parent control's `FormGroup`.

Parent component TypeScript file:

```
// imports go here

@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  templateUrl: "./parent.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./parent.component.css"]
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    // Just create a typical FormGroup.
    fg: FormGroup;

    // Instantiate the FormGroup using your preferred method.
    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.fg = this.fb.group({ FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" });
    }
}
```

Parent component template file:

```
<!-- Bind a form in the parent component to your FormGroup. -->
<form [formGroup]="fg">
    <!-- Reference the child component.  No need for @Inputs or fancy bindings. -->
    <app-child></app-child>
</form>
```

Child component TypeScript file:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlContainer } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  // Ask the framework for a ControlContainer whose control property has the goods.
  constructor(public controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Child component template file:

```
<!-- Finally, bind some top-level element to the imported FormGroup. -->
<fieldset [formGroup]="controlContainer.control">
    <legend>Reusable Controls Go Here</legend>

    <div>
        First Name
        <!-- Now, use the FormGroup per normal. -->
        <input formControlName="FirstName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Last Name
        <input formControlName="LastName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Accessing the FormGroup
        <!-- You can even get fancy. -->
        {{ controlContainer.control.get('FirstName')?.errors | json }}
    </div>
</fieldset>
```